# Solve Inequalities to find boundary for one variable

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

**X<0 and Y<0 :**  as we are having sorted array and we are picking two pairs.

**arr:** `-7, -3 ,3, 4, 7`

so I can have number in this way `(-7, -3)`, `(-3, -7) <--- this won't be the case as I am having order`. so `(X<Y)`
hence `min(|X|, |Y|) = |Y|`

```
|X-Y|<= min(|X|, |Y|)
```

---

```
|X-Y| <= |Y|
```

now how to solve to get range for Y in terms of X to get its boundary which holds true.

I have two conditions to satisfy

```
min(|x-y|,|x+y|)<=min(|x|,|y|)
max(|x-y|,|x+y|)>=max(|x|,|y|)
```

so designing the cases.
Currently stuck at `x<0 and y<0`

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).